# Prove the following fibonacci sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$h_0 = 0 $

$
h_1 = 1 $

$h_j = h_{j-1}+ h_{j-2} $ for  j >=2

I want to prove with strong induction that
$h_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^j - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^j \right]$ for j>=0

For the base cases,

n=0,
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^0 - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^0 \right]$ = 0

n=1, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^1- \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^1 \right] = 1$

Which agrees with $h_0$ and $  h_1$.

I know that I assume $h_p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^p - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^p \right]$ for p>= 0
and show that $h_{p+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^{p+1} - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}2 \right)^{p+1} \right]$. My problem is, I don't how where to show that this is true.

Comment: I believe in the case of fibonnaci you must assume for $h_p$ and $h_{p+1}$, then show for $h_{p+2}$, or something to that effect. You started with two base cases, so that shouldn't throw a wrench in the inductive process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

the caracteristic equation is

$x^2-x-1=0$

the solutions are
$x_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
$x_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

thus

$h_n=ax_1^n+bx_2^n$

we get the constant $a$ and $b$ using
initial conditions.